# How to screen two shaders in environmental view

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine, skybox

How could I mix these two shaders so I could screen one over another?

Attached here the blender file

[image]

I have these two shaders (in environment texture)

Shader1
[image]

Shader2
[image]

And I want to screen one over another like this (done in photoshop)
[image]

However, After trying with several mix nodes (color, math, mix shaders, add shaders) I can just get some mixture out of them like this:
[image]

Comment: @moonboots I just uploaded the blender file.

And indeed, the issue is that the red cloud is not over the white, but rather they mix together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is an unconventional texture.. you're displaying a distorted texture-space,as color, rather than a color, in a distorted texture-space.. but if it gets you where you want to go, why not?

Perhaps, to get you some control over the mix, without depending on the visible color in the texture, you could introduce an alpha channel to whatever colors ypou choose to put in the color-ramp of the foreground texture:

[image]

..and use the alpha to control the masking, with something in the way to control the range..

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I am not sure what you mean with "you're displaying a distorted texture-space,as color, rather than a color, in a distorted texture-space"

Could you explain it a bit more? I am not an expert in blender so I am open to find out better ways to achieve the same :)

My idea is to create clouds over clouds with different shapes to create some sort of nebula :)

Comment: If you plug the various outputs of the Texture Coordinate node straight  into a material output, you will see colors. They are the encoding of the X,Y, and Z of the texture-space as colors: the 'XYZ addresses' of the shading-points shown as R, G, and B. Typically, those numbers would be used _as_  XYZ, not RGB, and  plugged into the Vector input of various textures, to tell the textures (which provide the colors) _where_ to go, not displayed as colors in their own right. You might find you have more flexibility if you use them that way... but I've nothing against their creative use! :)

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not sure what you're doing but you could create this setup for your red cloud node group:

[image]

Then plug the 2 groups this way:

[image]

And you'll get that:

[image]

I hope someone has a cleaner way though  ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input, indeed it is a very good solution, although I mark the other answer as the accepted one as it adds the map range, which i think its interesting as it helps to remove those "sharp edges" a bit.